# Excel (If & Randbetween)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to generate an IF statement with Randbetween in excel, 
=IF(K3:K34=TRUE RANDBETWEEN(L3,L34))

I'm trying to say that If column K3-K34 are true, take the names in the column next to that column, randomize the names and insert them wherever I have highlighted.
I'm probably way off, but can someone help me rewrite the statement.

Comment: could you give some example data sets and expected output.

Comment: In Column A, Rows 3-20: Title is Position. In Column B, Row 3-20: Team Member. In Column C, Rows 3-20: Position. In Column D, Rows 3-20: Team Member. In Column L I have the names of the team members I would like to randomly assign in Columns B & D rows 3-20, the names are from row 3-34. In column M I have checks marks that i will check if the team member is present. I linked each check mark 3-34 to column K where True or False appear depending on the check mark next to the team members name.

Comment: The code you sent works however, I don't want one name to appears twice. Do you recommend me using another tool for this?  Sorry I would insert an image but I have no idea how.

Comment: Did you follow my instruction to change the `$N$2:N2` reference to the cell directly above where you first put the formula?  If you had there would be no duplicates.

Comment: what would I do if I want the reference cell to be continued to another column?

Answer (score 2):

RandBetween returns a number between two numbers not a cell value between two cells.

This will return a unique list randomly organized:

```
=INDEX(L:L,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$3:$K$34)/(($K$3:$K$34)*(COUNTIF($N$2:N2,$L$3:$L$34)=0)),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF($K$3:$K$34,TRUE)-ROW(1:1)+1)))
```

Put in N3 and copy down.  The formula must be placed in a cell with at least one cell above it, the value in that cell does not matter as long as it is not included in J3:J34.  The reference $N$2:N2 must refer to the cell above where the formula is first place.  Pay special attention to the absolute/Relative reference as it is important that range grow as it is dragged down.

It will iterate through the range and create an array of row numbers that are true in K3:K34 and the value in L3:L34 has not already been used.  Then it will randomly select one of those row numbers and return that to the INDEX.  The Index will then return the value in that row.

[image]